# How to optimize css styles

Tags: html, css, optimization

I have a multiple groups of elements with identical inner elements, only the group container with different id. to styling the groups elements, I obtained a CSS code that contain about 50 classes with same parent id, I want to know if there are a possibility to not rewrite 50 times the same parent id.

Bellow a simple example with 2 groups with only 6 elements.

```css
[data-id="15HB2mz7"] .class-01,
[data-id="15HB2mz7"] .class-02,
[data-id="15HB2mz7"] .class-03,
[data-id="15HB2mz7"] .class-04,
[data-id="15HB2mz7"] .class-05,
[data-id="15HB2mz7"] .class-06 {
  color: red;
}

[data-id="58lmB1M"] .class-01,
[data-id="58lmB1M"] .class-02,
[data-id="58lmB1M"] .class-03,
[data-id="58lmB1M"] .class-04,
[data-id="58lmB1M"] .class-05,
[data-id="58lmB1M"] .class-06 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Group 01 -->
<div data-id="15HB2mz7">
  <div class="class-01">
    <div class="class-02">
      <div class="class-03">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-04">
    <div class="class-05">
      <div class="class-06">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Group 02 -->
<div data-id="58lmB1M">
  <div class="class-01">
    <div class="class-02">
      <div class="class-03">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-04">
    <div class="class-05">
      <div class="class-06">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Something like `[data-id="15HB2mz7"] div { color:red; }`... is it too simple? (^_^;)

Comment: @ReSedano my project contain a very complex HTML structure with different tags and classes names and somme classes have deferent color style no way to this this solution ▪‿▪.

Comment: I imagined... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How about a second [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) only for the class attribute?  You could use a prefix attribute selector to be a little more specific with it too.

```css
[data-id="15HB2mz7"] [class^="class-"] {
  color: red;
}

[data-id="58lmB1M"] [class^="class-"] {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Group 01 -->
<div data-id="15HB2mz7">
  <div class="class-01">
    <div class="class-02">
      <div class="class-03">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-04">
    <div class="class-05">
      <div class="class-06">test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Group 02 -->
<div data-id="58lmB1M">
  <div class="class-01">
    <div class="class-02">
      <div class="class-03">test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="class-04">
    <div class="class-05">
      <div class="class-06">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: my classes names are not like in this examples, one name does not resemble the other.

Comment: @MustaphaFersaoui Not in any way?  If that's the case, the best option I can think of is the use a CSS precompiler like SASS or LESS.  The output CSS will be just as ugly as the original, but it would be easier to write at least.

Comment: That's what I thought, too! Thank you!